# Why does the accuracy of classification drop with the increase of features used when using RFECV in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm, rfe

Could anyone please explain me why the accuracy of classification drops with the increase of features used in recursive feature elimination with cross-validation in Scikit-learn? From the example reported in Scikit-learn documentation here: [Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.7/auto_examples/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html), it seems that the best classification results are produced when using 7 features. However when using 17 features, the accuracy drops by 25%. How is this possible? I would expect the accuracy to constantly increase with the addition of features.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the docs you are referring to is OLD. The current version of the example is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#example-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py)
If removing features would always decrease performance, there would be no point in doing feature selection.
Removing features that are unrelated to the target will decrease overfitting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Even in your example the accuracy drops from 0.82 to 0.73 when using 3 and 25 features. What is the reason for this? I would still expect by removing features to see a constant decrease in performance, and there is still a point in doing feature selection in this case (e.g. if you need 3000 vs 30 features to produce 0.8 and 0.75 accuracy respectively, I would choose the second).

Comment: As I said, removing features that are unrelated can decrease overfitting, and therefore provide better generalization.